# Internals of a tree

Tags: python

I'm trying to return the internals of a tree and the length of the internals list and here's what I've come up with so far:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):

        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def internals(self):
        leaves = []
        internals = []
        if self.left == None and self.right == None:
            leaves.append(self.item)
        else:
            if self.left:
                itls = self.left.internals()
                internals.extend(itls)
            if self.right:
                itls = self.right.internals()
                internals.extend(itls)
            internals.append(self.item)
        return internals

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    tree = Node(10,Node(3, Node(4)),Node(7, Node(8)))
    print(tree.internals())
```

It works fine returning the list of internals,

example:

```
    tree = Node(10,Node(3, Node(4)),Node(7, Node(8)))
    print(tree.internals())
    [3, 7, 10]
```

But if I try to return the length of the list with the list of internals it seems like my entire list gets deformed and here's where I am not to sure what is going on.

to return the length of the list of internals as well I just changed the last line of the internals method to **return internals, len(internals)**

but when I call the method on the tree it returns the list of internals and the length of the list but the problem is somehow the list got deformed and therefore the length of the list is wrong as well.

```
    tree = Node(10,Node(3, Node(4)),Node(7, Node(8)))
    print(tree.internals())
    ([[[], 0, 3], 3, [[], 0, 7], 3, 10], 5)
```

Not sure why that happened so I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out the problem.

Comment: You are calling `internals()` from within your function, did you account for the fact that you're getting different results after the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mess up the recursive calls, if you add the length of the list to it.
Here is a version that works. I added an additional method to call the recursive one.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):

        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def internals_impl(self):
        leaves = []
        internals = []
        if self.left == None and self.right == None:
            leaves.append(self.item)
        else:
            if self.left:
                itls = self.left.internals_impl()
                internals.extend(itls)
            if self.right:
                itls = self.right.internals_impl()
                internals.extend(itls)
            internals.append(self.item)
        return internals

    def internals(self):
        nodes = self.internals_impl()
        return len(nodes),nodes  

if(__name__ == "__main__"):  

    tree = Node(10,Node(3, Node(4)),Node(7, Node(8)))
    print(tree.internals())
```

Result is:

```
(3, [3, 7, 10])
```